# Vlc, banshee doesn't playing song when tuxguitar opened!

Tags: pulseaudio, vlc, banshee, tuxguitar

I install tuxguitar 1.2 using custom soundfont from package fluid-soundfont-gm and fluid-soundfont-gs.
The sound i got from the custom fontsound was great. But when tuxguitar opened: VlC,Banshee, and other media player cannot playing song(Idle).

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Is pulesaudio installed?

Comment: 12.04 Pulse Installed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you guitar software may be locking the codec needed to play the file, try Ubuntu software center search for "restricted extras", 3rd party codecs are not under the ubuntu free license and not installed, check for one of the non free codec updates. If I don't run this codec update my vervid monkey doesn't even play an mp3 but jukebox is installed, there are a plethora of software versions available fro different vendors fddshow mp4 2.64 the new 2.65 is recommended https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8eSog_bhsk

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras was installed

Comment: im not a new person on ubuntu!before i using the custom soundfont on tuxguitar, i can playing song on banshee when tuxguitar open